# Unreleased Kanye West Chain Heavy album

Tags: history, rap, hip-hop

8 years ago, I downloaded a Kanye West album called *Chain Heavy*.
I've always wondered about the history behind this album: maybe half of the songs are available on YouTube; nothing on other streaming services. The album does not appear in [Kanye West's album discography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West#Discography) WP entry or anywhere else.

This is one of my favorite West albums, so I'm quite surprised to see that there's nothing on it.
There's already been a [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kanye/comments/i05roy/what_happened_to_chain_heavy/) topic on this, but the answer does not satisfy me as the tracklist includes songs that are not from GOOD Fridays.

You'll find below the cover and tracklist.

Any information is appreciated.

[image: Kanye West Chain Heavy cover]
[image: Kanye West Chain Heavy tracklist]